# Determine the equations of the tangents to the curve $y=2x^2+3$ that pass through point $(2,3)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am unsure of how to answer this question. All I have found is the slope of the tangents: $y'= 4x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Figure 1 Showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBg0M.png) (Figure 1 is just for general reference)

You have a 2nd order polynomial $y = f(x)$ which we know is a parabola. You have a point that lies outside of the parabola $P\,(x_P,y_P)$. There are two points on the parabola $(a\,\,and\,\,b)$ who's tangent lines pass through point $P$. The tangent line that passes through points $a$ and $P$ is defined by $y=a(x) = f'(x_a)x + b_a$ and the tangent line that passes through points $b$ and $P$ is defined by $y=b(x) = f'(x_b)x + b_b$. First we need to find the slope of $f(x)$ then solve for $x_a$ and $x_b$.

1. Find the slope of $f(x)$ by taking the derivative
   $$\begin{align}y=f(x)&=2x^2+3\\\\f'(x)&=4x\end{align}$$,
2. Solve for $x_a$ and $x_b$. Looking at **Figure 1** both points $a\,(x_a,y_a)\,\, and\,\,b\,(x_b, y_b)$ have been defined as $[x, f(x)]$, this is done so we can find a general solution using the **[Slope Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope)**
   $$\begin{align}m&=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}\\\\Making\,\,substitutions\,\,&with\,\,our\,\,function,\,\, derivative,\,\,and\,\,point\\\\f'(x)&=\frac{f(x)-y_P}{x-x_P}\end{align}$$
   The above states that derivative at $x$ is equal to the slope between the point defined by $f(x)$ and our known point $P$. Now we will substitute our known values into the slope formula and solve for x.
   $$\begin{align}x_P&=2\\y_p&=3\\\\4x&=\frac{2x^2+3-3}{x-2}\\\\0&=\frac{2x^2+3-3}{x-2}-4x\\\\&=2x^2+3-3-4x(x-2)\\\\&=2x^2-0-4x^2+8x\\\\&\Rightarrow 2x^2-8x+0\,\,\,(Multiplied\,\,both\,\,sides\,\,by\,\,-1)\end{align}$$
   We now have a [Quadratic Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) where $a=2$, $b=-8$, and $c=0$. We can solve for x using the quadratic formula.
   $$\begin{align}x&=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}\\\\&=\frac{8\pm8}{4}\\\\&\Rightarrow x_a=0,\,\,x_b=4\end{align}$$
3. Now we can solve for the slope at points $a$ and $b$.
   $$\begin{align}m_a&=f'(x_a)\\&=4(0)\\&=0\\\\m_b&=f'(x_b)\\&=4(4)\\&=16\end{align}$$
4. Now we will solve for $b_a$ and $b_b$ in the tangent line equations using the values we found for $x$. We will evaluate the tangent line equations at point $P$.
   $$
     \begin{align}
       x_a&=0\\
       x_b&=4\\
       x_P&=2\\
       y_P&=3\\\\
       y_P=a(x_P)&=m_ax+b_a\\\\
       3&=(0)(2)+b_a\\\\
       &=0+b_a\\\\
       b_a&=3\\\\
       y_P=b(x_P)&=m_bx+b_b\\\\3&=(16)(2)+b_b\\\\&=32+b_b\\\\b_b&=-29\end{align}$$
5. Putting it all together... We have solved for the slope and y-intercept for the lines tangent to points $a$ and $b$ which pass through point $P$. Now we will substitute the values into our tangent equations.

$$\begin{align}
  y&=mx+b\\\\\\
  &For\,\,the\,\,tangent\,\,line\,\,at\,\,a\\
  a(x)&=m_ax+b_a\\\\
  &=(0)x+3\\\\
  &=3\\\\\\
  &For\,\,the\,\,tangent\,\,line\,\,at\,\,b\\
  b(x)&=m_bx+b_b\\\\
  &=16x-29\end{align}$$

6. Check that $f(x_a) = a(x_a)$ and $f(x_b) = b(x_b)$
   $$\begin{align}f(0)&=a(0)\\2(0)^2+3&=3\\\\f(4)&=b(4)\\2(4)^2+3&=16(4)-29\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's a classic quadratic equation problem in disguise. Let the tangent line be $y = mx+b$ as usual. This line passes through the point $(2,3)$ implies $3 = 2m+b \implies b = 3 - 2m\implies y = mx + 3 - 2m$. We now determine $m$ and hence the line is known. Since the line is a tangent line, this means it intersects the parabola given by $y = 2x^2+3$ at only $1$ point. It means that the equation: $2x^2+3 = mx + 3-2m$ or $2x^2 -mx + 2m = 0$ has exactly one real solution. Thus $\triangle = m^2 - 16m = 0\implies m = 0,16$. Thus there are $2$ tangent lines to the parabola that goes through the point $(2,3)$, namely: $y = 3$, and $y = 16x-29$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The equation of tangent at $P(h,2h^2+3)$

will be $$\dfrac{y-(2h^2+3)}{x-h}=4h$$

Now this line must pass through $(2,3)$

Answer (score 0):

Let the point of intersection of the tangent and curve be $(x_{1},y_{1})$

$y'=4x_{1}$

Also $y'=\frac{y_{1}-3}{x_{1}-2}\ \ \ $ ....as $(2,3)$ doesn't lie on the curve

$y_{1}=2x_{1}^2 + 3$

$\implies 4x_{1}= \frac{2x_{1}^2 +3-3}{x_{1}-2}$

$4x_{1}\cdot(x_{1}-2)=2x_{1}^2$

Now you could solve for $x_{1}$ and find $y_{1}$ and subsequently, you could determine the  equations too!